# React - Render dynamic list of components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list of keys which represent a custom React component. Based on this list I want to render the appropriate component. I have a reference to each component so I can create a map of `key -> Component` which allows me to create a list of my components. However I have not found a way to render this list.

Example.:

```
input: ["componentA", "componentB", "componentC"]

output:
<ComponentA />
<ComponentB />
<ComponentC />
```

This is what I got so far, however I'm not sure how to render the list of components:

```
function renderElements(keys) {
  const components = {
    componentA: ComponentA,
    componentB: ComponentB,
    componentC: ComponentC,
  };

  const componentsToRender = keys.map(key => components[key]);

  return (
    <div>
      {componentsToRender}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Show us the code that you have so far to try and make this happen.

Comment: You need to map array and return component. Not much logic I guess.

Comment: component should be in capital.like this: ["ComponentA", "ComponentB", "ComponentC"]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What worked for me:

```
render() {
  const components = [ComponentA, ComponentB, ComponentC] // references to components
  return (
    <div>
      {components.map((comp, i) => React.createElement(comp, { key: i })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Had to use a reference to the component and had to use `React.createElement` due to problems with nested JSX (might be Typescript related).

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It should work.

```
 render()
    {
      const input=["ComponentA", "ComponentB", "ComponentC"]

       return(
             <div>
               {
                  input.map((comp,i)=>){
                      return <{comp} key={i} />
                    }
                }
             </div>

        )
    }
```

> Note:  input= ["ComponentA", "ComponentB", "ComponentC"];Custom
>   component name should be in Capital

Comment: Global variable leakage.

Comment: @dfsq Please explain . Not sure about your feedback.

Comment: @dfsq are you talking about: input=["ComponentA", "ComponentB", "ComponentC"].

Comment: @dfsq . It was typo. I didn't checked properly.  Thanks for pointing.

Comment: I had some issues using a string reference and this JSX syntax with typescript. Using React.createElement with the reference to the component worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
render() {
    return (
       <div>
          {componentsToRender.map((Component, key) => (<Component key={key}/>))}
       <div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason using the map function as specified in the [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) didn't work for me for any component/element that's not an li, I had to explicitly specify a return statement.

```
options = optionsArray.map(o => {
    // replace option with your component name
    return <option key={o.name} value={o.name}>{o.name}</option>
})
```

then I rendered the generated elements. You can do it inline too if you want.

```
<div>
    {options}
</div>
```